# stage force render / redraw

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Normally I would listen to the ENTER_FRAME event and execute code each time a frame gets rendered.. But for my application this is too slow. The time between 2 ENTER_FRAME events is 40 milliseconds. Doesn't matter if I change my framerate.

So is it possible to force flash to redraw/render the frame without listening to events? I tried the stage.invalidate() method and changing the framerate but it doesn't improve anything (stage.invalidate() doesn't do anything actually)

I did a small test to see the average time between the ENTER_FRAME and the EXIT_FRAME event:

```
private var beginTime:Number;
private var endTime:Number;

public function init():void {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
    addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, exitFrame);
}

private function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    beginTime = new Date().getTime();

    if(endTime) {
        trace(beginTime - endTime);
    }
}

private function exitFrame(e:Event):void {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
}
```

If I am right the ENTER_FRAME event is fired before the rendering of that frame and the EXIT_FRAME event is fired after the rendering. So after the EXIT_FRAME event the rendering is complete and the app will dispatch an ENTER_FRAME event.
The average time between those two events is 52 milliseconds. And I want to shorten that time

Bytheway I have set my framerate to 180 for this test

Comment: Could you update your question to be more specific? Perhaps show some code?

Comment: Regardless of if this is possible, it might actually be a bad idea.
If the time between ENTER_FRAME events is 40 milliseconds, even if you change the frame rate then that is probably because it takes at least 40 milliseconds to render the stage.
Attempting to render it more often is probably not going to make your app faster

Comment: Timothy's advice is pretty good. Try to profile your app to find potential bottle necks either in memory or CPU. You can also try [Scout](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=175)

Comment: Timothy's answer makes really good sense. But I believe that after the EXIT_FRAME event the rendering is done so the next frame could be rendered immediately after that event. I've updated my question

Oh and scout looks really cool, i'm going to try and see if it can get me any result :)

Comment: You need to consider both code execution and rendering for a single frame, even seen this article? http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/

Comment: i believe that maximum framerate for flash player (at least these days) is limited at 60fps - it wont go faster than that, whatever you set frame rate to be

Answer (score 1):

stage.Invalidate will force the stage to redraw. Its not suggested you should fix your time problem first.