# Trigger a frame update in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've encountered a case where I'm calling code that causes a flicker in a bitmap data. Without changing the frame rate to a much higher value (don't know if this is possible to change dynamically at runtime) is it possible to redraw the frame quickly?

In the old days you could cause Flash Player to manually update the frame by calling `updateAfterEvent()`. Does this still work? Is there another way to update the frame?

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
// force redraw
var updateEvent:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE);
updateEvent.updateAfterEvent();
```

If it's local variables will this get garbage collected?

Comment: Google > as3 force redraw > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726357/stage-force-render-redraw Google > as3 stage frame rate > http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate

Comment: _"I'm calling code that causes a flicker in a bitmap data"_ it would be interesting to have minimal test code to re-create this issue. Then solutions can be suggested...

Comment: what you mean by flicker? Could you record video?

Comment: I'll try to post some example code or a gif but it happens when I'm assigning new bitmap data to a spark image component source.

Comment: The usual way to prevent this kind of 'flicker' is to have a second image component, set the new bitmapdata to that, and swap the image components once loading is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're changing a something during enter frame listener, it should get updated automatically. Otherwise, use `updateAfterEvent()` in a non-enterframe listener.

```
function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //  ... code that changes something
    e.updateAfterEvent();
}
```